# Windows storage server 2019 exported NFS: chown permission denied

Tags: nfs, windows-server-2019, network-attached-storage

I've not been a windows server guy for a long time, so I'm not super familiar with the newer MS server OSes... but I'm trying to link up my linux host to a NAS at a customer site.  Their NAS is running Windows storage server 2019 and has some existing SMB shares that I'm also trying to export via NFS. The NAS isn't a member of their domain.

I enabled the NFS sharing and under the advanced sharing setup Auth_SYS and "Enable unmapped user access" with Read-Write and "Allow root access".

I can mount this share and, as root, I can chown things... but as a user, even though I have ownership of the parent folder, I can't chown anything inside.

Currently I'm searching technet but so far nothing useful has come up.  I only have limited access to the storage server when one of the windows admins is screen sharing with me.

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: What I have recently found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923788/windows-server-2019-server-for-nfs-uid-gid-mapping-with-auth-sys) is something to test... I'll try setting up an ID mapping uid and gid to an existing windows account.

Comment: I can't seem to make this ID mapping thing work...  and even setting the share to use these generated SIDs, I still get permission denied errors setting permissions as a user...